# Shopify Brand Colour in custom.css

Tags: css, shopify

I have set a brand primary color in Shopify > Settings > Brand

I would use this color in a custom.css.

Is there a way to do this (I don't want to hard code the colour in the css)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `.css.liquid` file, you could try some version of:

```css
.container {
  background: {{ shop.brand.colors.primary[0].background }};
}
```

Which would compile to:

```css
.container {
  background: #0b101f;
}
```

More docs on the subject of including [brand assets](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/brand) and specifically [colours](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/brand_color):

- https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/brand
- https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/brand_color